# XML to wordpress real estate website

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xml-parsing

I want to integrate my wordpress realestate website into jupix website and get data that i upload in jupix through xml feed.

http://services2.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=35871cc1b6d9ec6237aaaf94aa0e0836&passphrase=cvYG9f

This is a demo API.

I want to get the demo code that will be integrated to website in WP and put that into a property listing like 
http://www.cowleyproperty.com/brochure.php?p=CPCCPC4601

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
$xmlparseado = simplexml_load_file('http://services2.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=35871cc1b6d9ec6237aaaf94aa0e0836&passphrase=cvYG9f');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xmlparseado);
echo "</pre>"; exit;
```

Comment: Call to undefined function wp_remote_get() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

For others finding this topic via Google as I did, I can recommend using Property Hive which has an 'Import' add on. One of the formats supported is Jupix, amongst others:

https://wp-property-hive.com/addons/property-import/

Hope this helps!